# How to get Json

Tags: android

**Is there way to get this json Code in android i did some code in can get the Food_id name but can't get the Files array**

```
"products":[
     {
         "food_id":"1",
         "name":"Biryani",
         "files":[
             {
                 "path":"http:\/\/www.studentbiryani.ca\/student_biryani\/index\/images\/biryani-icon.png",
                 "title":"biryani-icon.png",
                 "size":1229,
                 "type":"image"
             }
         ]
     }
```

**My Android Code**

package student.briyani;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.ExifInterface;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Food extends Activity {
    ImageView licon;
    ImageView menu_btn;
    Intent i;
    Intent intent;
    ListView lv;
    String[] foodIcon;
    String[] FoodText;
    public HashMap<String, String> catagories = new HashMap<String, String>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_food);

        licon=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.l_icon);
        menu_btn=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.menu_btn);

        i=new Intent(this,Location.class);
        intent=new Intent(this,SilideMenu.class);

        new getFoodCategory().execute();

        lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.food_list);
        menu_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        licon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }// end of onCreate method

    class getFoodCategory extends AsyncTask<String, String, String[]> {


        @Override
         protected void onPreExecute() {
             super.onPreExecute();
             // Showing progress dialog
//             pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Jokecatagory.this);
//             pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
//             pDialog.setCancelable(false);
//             pDialog.show();

         }
         protected void onPostExecute(String []result) {
             super.onPostExecute(result);

                // lv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(Food.this,FoodText,foodIcon));
                 //pDialog.dismiss();
             }

        @Override
        protected String [] doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            JSONArray Food_Text = null;

            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> jCatagory = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            getFoods cat=new getFoods();
            String url="";
            String jsonStr = cat.viewRecords(url, getFoods.GET, null);
            Log.d("Records", jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr!= null) {

             try {
                 JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                 //System.out.print("JsonObject"+jsonObj);
                 //Log.d("jsonObject", "new json Object");
                 // Getting JSON Array node
                 Food_Text = jsonObj.getJSONArray("products");
                // FoodPath = jsonObj.getJSONArray("products");
                // Log.d("json aray", "user point array");
        //         int len =jCat.length();
                 //Log.d("len", "get array length"+len);


                 for(int i=0; i<Food_Text.length();i++) {

                     JSONObject c = Food_Text.getJSONObject(i);
                     String foodId = c.getString("food_id");
                   //  Log.d("Cat Id", catId);
                     String food_name = c.getString("name");
                   //  String FoodPath = c.getString("files");

                     //String path=c.getString("path");

                     //    Log.d("Cat_Name", cat_name);

                     //  hashmap for single match
                     // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

//                     catagories.put("cat_id"+i, catId);
                     catagories.put("cat_name"+i, food_name);
                  //   catagories.put("path"+1,FoodPath);
                   }

                 FoodText=new String [catagories.size()];


                  for(int k=0; k<catagories.size();k++){
                      FoodText[k]=catagories.get("cat_name"+k);
                      //foodIcon[k]=catagories.get("foodIcon"+k);
          //        jokesCates[k]=catagories.get("cat_name"+k);
                    System.out.print("cat_name"+catagories.get("cat_name"+k)+"\n");
                }

                  for(int i=0;i<catagories.size();i++){
                     Log.d("FoodText", FoodText[i]);
                    // Log.d("FoodIcon", foodIcon[i]);
                 }
                     }

             catch (JSONException e) {
                 Log.d("catch", "in the catch");
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }

            } else {
             Log.e("JSON Data", "Didn't receive any data from server!");
            }

            return null;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stubs

         } 
    }
}//end of class
```

Comment: It's interesting that you get one array correctly, but not the second. When you tried to access it as an array, what happened? Also, please include only the *relevant* code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"files" is another array, not a String and not a JSONObject. Therefor use something like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<Food_Text.length();i++) {

        JSONObject c = Food_Text.getJSONObject(i);
        String foodId = c.getString("food_id");
        //  Log.d("Cat Id", catId);
        String food_name = c.getString("name");
        //  String FoodPath = c.getString("files");

        JSONArray files = c.getJSONArray("files");

        for(int k = 0; k<files.length();k++){
            JSONObject filesPart = files.getJSONObject(k);
            String FoodPath = filesPart.getString("path");
        }

        catagories.put("cat_name"+i, food_name);
        //   catagories.put("path"+1,FoodPath);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to parse an Array as a String, which is wrong.

After the statement

```
String food_name = c.getString("name");
```

do this

```
JSONArray files = c.getJSONArray("files");
```

then run the loop for it to get the values inside it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it ;

```
String files = jsonObj.getString("files");
```

Comment: Hey there i can't post the new question i have reached at limit i am facing a new issue any one resolove this

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
for(int i=0; i<Food_Text.length();i++) {
    JSONObject c = Food_Text.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONArray files = c.getJSONArray("files");

    for (int j = 0; j < files.length(); j++){
        JSONObject file = files.getJSONObject(j);
        String path = file.getString("path");
    }
}
```